# Facebook likebox display face incorrect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have problem using facebook like on my page.
If i login on facebook, this the picture:

[image: problem using facebook like]

As you can see, picture showing 8 item, and there say 7 people. The real condition is just only 6 people.

This the other picture if i not logged on facebook:

[image: problem using facebook like]

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=25399293xxx";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=253992937944977" data-width="272" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

Any ideas? how can I fix this?